# Why does Leaflet layer control require null to be expanded by default

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-layer-control

I have the following code which is used the create a Leaflet layer control and keep it open by default:-

`const layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null,  {collapsed:false, position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);`.

What is the function of the **null** value added to the code. If I remove the **null** I get an error :-

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_leaflet_id' in false***. This error is visible from the browser console.

If I add an overlay layer to the code, I have to remove the **null** in order for the layer control widget to be added to the map with default setting:-

```
const layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays, {collapsed:false, position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

I have tried to search the documentation and other online resources for the explanation but could not get any.

Comment: Please pay attention to the type of the constructor parameters, as documented in https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers

Comment: Clear from the documentation. Must have missed it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an explanation based on what I understood from the documentation link in the comment of [@IvanSanchez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53755/ivansanchez). In case it might the useful for someone else.

I guess the null value acts as a placeholder for the omitted object **when adding layer control options** in the line of code

```
const layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null,  {collapsed:false, position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

Below is the part of the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) that expalins it properly

> The first argument passed when creating the layers control is the base
> layers object. The second argument is the overlays object. Both
> arguments are optional: you can pass just a base layers object by
> omitting the second argument, or just an overlays objects by passing
> null as the first argument. In each case, the omitted layer type will
> not appear for the user to select.